# Why are values being assigned to the next element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, structure

I am using Visual Studio 12, and I created a very simple array of structures:

```
struct testFloatStruct {
   double A;
   double B;
};
struct testFloatStruct threeSetsOfFloats[4];
```

That creates a total of six values, and I have no trouble assigning a value to the very first of those six, namely, element [0].A

However, when I assign a value to any of the others, the value **following** it is altered. For example, when I do this:

```
threeSetsOfFloats[0].B = 0.2;
```

The debugger shows that as soon as that statement is executed, the following element in he array, **[1].A**, picks up a bizarre value.

I am not too familiar with Visual Studio since I was previously using the Borland compiler, so I don't know if I'm setting something wrong with the hundreds of compiler options.

I simplified this test project to the point where it only has six assignment statements. I have two screen images and more information, along with a zip file of the project so that you can try it yourself:

http://www.hugequestions.com/c/Array_of_structures_problem.html

Comment: Six? I think you mean eight.

Comment: Can you post the full code of your six-assignments-simplified version (here)?

Comment: Pure speculation: Maybe, since you don't initialize the values, the debugger doesn't actually check the values, and just reports whatever value it wants. Then when you write to one of the values in the array, it updates all of them to what's actually stored there.

Comment: Did you try to declare as `struct testFloatStruct threeSetsOfFloats[];` and initializate the struct with `new` (`MyStruct [] struct = new MyStruct[3]; `) to see if you have the same result?

Comment: @CrApHeR, Does that even work in C++/CLI? It certainly doesn't in standard C++.

Comment: I'm Sorry, I had misunderstood the question. 
My example was for C#, it does not work for C++.

Comment: @chris, I had 6 assignments, but I created an array to hold 8 values because the debugger was showing that when I assigned a value to [6], a value was appearing in [7] instead.  However, as I mentioned in my response to ejsd1989 (below), after using sprintf to show me the values, I find that the values are correct, even though the debugger is showing incorrect values.  Perhaps it is a bug in the debugger.

Comment: @deviantfan, the 6 assignment statements are exactly like the one listed above.  
threeSetsOfFloats[0].A = 0.1f;  
threeSetsOfFloats[0].B = 0.2f;  
threeSetsOfFloats[1].A = 1.1f;  
threeSetsOfFloats[1].B = 1.2f;  
threeSetsOfFloats[2].A = 2.1f;  
threeSetsOfFloats[2].B = 2.2f;  
As I mentioned in my other comments, I now think it is bug with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with the following in debugger displayed the correct values during each iteration through the for loops

```
struct testFloatStruct {
   double A;
   double B;
};
struct testFloatStruct threeSetsOfFloats[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    threeSetsOfFloats[i].A = 0.43;
    threeSetsOfFloats[i].B = 0.32;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cout << threeSetsOfFloats[i].A << endl;
    cout << threeSetsOfFloats[i].B << endl;
}
```

Now, i do see the random values in memory for the uninitialized data in the array. You should be able to stop that by initializing your struct variables:

```
struct testFloatStruct {
   double A;
   double B;

   testFloatStruct() {
   A = 0;
   B = 0;
   }
};
struct testFloatStruct threeSetsOfFloats[4];
```

Comment: I initialized the structure as you suggested but that didn't change anything. 

However, instead of using cout, I used sprintf to see what the values look like when displayed in a string, and it showed the correct values in the string.

So, the debugger was showing a bizarre value in the watch window, but sprintf was showing the correct value!

All I can guess is that it must be some quirky problem with the debugger. Apparently, we cannot always trust the values in that watch window when dealing with arrays of structures.

Comment: The object had static storage duration, so it was already zeroed.